# Código para números primos hasta el 100

Tags: java

Cuando corro el programa me imprime los números correctos pero algunos se repiten (Ej: 7 es número primo, 7 en número primo, 7 es número primo) y no se como corregirlo. Alguno me ayuda?

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int max = 100;


        for(int x = 2; x <= max; x++){
            for(int i = 2; i < x; i++){
                if(x % i == 0)
                    break;
                else System.out.println(x + " es un número primo");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu algoritmo está mal planteado, entremos en el bucle for cuando x= 7

```
for(int x = 2; x <= max; x++){
    //Tomemos x=7
    for(int i = 2; i < x; i++){ //recorremos i=2 hasta 6
        if(x % i == 0)
        // (7%2)==0? falso, imprimimos 7 es un número primo, lo mismo pasa para i=3,4,5,6
          break;
        else System.out.println(x + " es un número primo"); 
    }
}
```

Te dejo un código funcional para hallar número primo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int max = 100;
        
    for(int x = 2; x <= max; x++){
        if(esPrimo(x)){
            System.out.println(x+" es primo");
        }
    }
       
}
    
public static boolean esPrimo(int numero){
    int contador = 2;
    boolean primo=true;
    while ((primo) && (contador!=numero)){
      if (numero % contador == 0)
            primo = false;
      contador++;
    }
    return primo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te pongo por aquí el código para obtener los números primos del 1 al 100.

Para tener en cuenta: un número primo es un número natural que tiene dos divisores positivos distintos: él mismo y el 1.

O lo que es lo mismo, un número primo es el que es divisible entre si mismo y 1.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean primo;
        System.out.println("Son números primos del 1 al 100:\n");
        // Estructura for
        for (int num = 2; num <= 100; num++) {
            primo = true;
            for (int i = num - 1; i > 1; i--) {
                if (num % i == 0) {
                    primo = false;
                    break;
                }//fin if
            }//fin for
            if (primo) {
                System.out.println(num + " es primo");
            }//fin if
        }//fin for

    }//fin main

}//fin clase
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por esta respuesta. Quería saber porque se usaba esta estructura "for (int i = num - 1; i > 1; i--)" y no "for (int i = 2; i > num; i++)

Comment: @FelipeSuaya ``for (int i = num - 1; i > 1; i--)``  y ``for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) `` realizan lo mismo ambos recorren del 2 hasta num-1

Answer (score 1):

Añado una alternativa, estaba en ella cuando se me adelantó Joshin

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //instanciamos la clase scanner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //pedimos el número hasta el que deseamos conocer los primero
    System.out.print("Hasta que número desea saber los números primos: ");
    //recogemos el número en la variable entera
    int max = teclado.nextInt();

    //imrpimimos el texto
    System.out.println("Son números primos: ");
    //creamos un bucle for con el límite del número introducido
    for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++){
        //recogemos en una variable booleana el return del método esPrimo y enviamos el número
        //correpondiente a la iteración del bucle
        boolean primo = esPrimo(i);
        //si el return es primo, lo sacamos por pantalla
        if (primo){
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
//método que nos dice si el número es primo que recibe por parámetro un entero (el de la iteración del bucle)
public static boolean esPrimo(int numero) {
    // El 0, 1 y 4 no son primos
    if (numero == 0 || numero == 1 || numero == 4) {
        //por lo que en esos números retonramos false
        return false;
    }
    //creamos un bucle para evaluar los números recibidos
    for (int x = 2; x < numero / 2; x++) {
        // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no es primo
        if (numero % x == 0)
            //si no es primo retornamos falso
            return false;
    }
    // Si no se pudo dividir por ninguno de los de arriba, sí es primo
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
/*Mostrar los 10 primeros números Primos: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29*/  
for(int i=2;i<=30;i++){
   if(esPrimo(i)){
       System.out.println(i);
   }
}
}
public static boolean esPrimo(int numero){       
    boolean primo=true;
    int cantDivisores=0;
    for(int i=2;i<numero;i++){
        if(numero%i==0){
            cantDivisores++;
        }
    }
    if(cantDivisores>0){
        primo =false;
    }else{
        primo =true;
    }
    return primo;
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).