# Programa que busca números primos no funciona correctamente

Tags: java, números-primos

Estoy intentando crear un sencillo programa que encuentre números primos entre los números 2 y 1000. Lo he intentado hacer de varias formas, pero el resultado siempre es el mismo, el programa me muestra todos los números, no solamente los que son primos.

Dejo por aquí el código, por si alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal y puede ayudarme:

```
public class primos {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean primo; 
        System.out.println("Números primos entre 2 y 1000: \n");
        System.out.print(2 + ", ");

        for(int i = 3; i <= 1000; i +=2) {
           primo = false;
           for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if(i % j == 0) {
                    break;    
                }
                else {
                    primo = true;
                }
           }

           if(primo) {
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para el registro... en tu primer ciclo, donde empiezas de 3 y te vas de 2 en 2, los primos no son los mismos que los impares, recuerdalo. Empiezas en 3, luego 5,7,9,11... Y si te percatas, te saltas el 2, que es el primer numero primo, es mejor ir de 1 en 1 recorriendo los 1,000 numeros

Comment: Revisa la siguiente [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/478692/193364) espero te sirva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que inicializar primo a true, y entonces, si es divisible por algun j, poner primo a false, y seguir haceuendo el break que ya se hace.

Quedaria así:

```
   for(int i = 3; i <= 1000; i +=2) {
       primo = true;
       for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if(i % j == 0) {
                primo = false;
                break;    
            }
       }

       if(primo) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. La solución que has puesto es la que más me ha ayudado y además el código es más limpio que el mío. 

Lo único que no entiendo, y que me falta por saber, es por qué el programa no funciona con el código que yo he puesto. Si te fijas, "primo", se inicia en "false" en cada iteración del primer bucle, entonces ¿Por qué no funciona como se supone que tiene que funcionar? No lo entiendo.

En cualquier caso, tu solución me ha ayudado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Digamos que un numero es primo/inocente hasta que se demuestre lo contrario (se encuentre un divisor/prueba), sino se encuentra divisor/prueba, es primo/inocente. :)

Comment: P.e., en tu codigo, el 15 : 15 % 2 != 0 --> primo = true. Pero 15 no es primo, se divide entre 3. Otro ejemp : 8 % 7 != 0 --> primo. Para todo n>=3: n % (n-1) != 0 --> primo, Por eso te salian todos primos. No basta con encontrar un j que no divida, sino que deben ser todos los j los que no dividan para decir "es primo".

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que la palabra reservada `break` hace que te salgas del bucle, por lo que es lógico que no te funcione como desees.
Yo crearía un método que devuelvan un valor booleano, por ejemplo:

```
    public boolean restoNoCero(int dividendo, int divisor){
    return dividendo % divisor != 0;

}
```

Y también crearía un array para guardar los valores que sean primos:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listaPrimos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

y con este método trabajaría en el bucle:

```
for(int i = 3; i < 1000; i++){

for(int j = 2; j < i; j++){
if(restoNoCero(i, j){
listaPrimos.add(i);

}

}
```

}

Y para verlos:

```
for(int k = 0; k < listaPrimos.size(); k++){
   System.out.print("Numeros primos: " + listaPrimos[i]);
}
```

No sé si me habré comido alguna llave. Espero que te sea útil. Un saludo y bienvenido

Comment: Muchas gracias. Aunque la solución que has puesto es válida para conseguir el objetivo, no es la respuesta que busco. 

Lo que busco es entender por qué el código que he puesto yo no funciona.

En cualquier caso, muchas gracias, siempre se aprenden cosas nuevas.